Meaning of Fourier expansions in Heisenberg's matrix mechanics
I am trying to figure out the passages Heisenberg followed in developing matrix mechanics as presented in his 1925 Umdeutung paper. In developing the virtual oscillators model, Heisenberg uses the Fourier expansions of x and p, which classically would have been the position and momentum of the atomic electron. By imposing the commutation relations between x and p, he ensures that they behave as matrixes. It is usually said that the coefficients in the Fourier expansions represent matrix coefficients. So, I think that these expansions are not to be interpreted literally, but only symbolically, since now x and p are represented by matrixes (which are not sums of functions of their elements, as the Fourier expansions are). Is it correct?

"Is it correct?" Is what correct? Maybe try adding some of the equations that you are asking about to your post (using MathJax). I don't think a lot of people are going to go out and find/read that 1925 paper.

Have you tried your luck with MSE, more suited to your type of question? You are not satisfied with the thorough WP?

At the time Heisenberg was developing a new description of nature where classical commutation relations were implemented/realized in terms of matrices.  He was trying to explain the quantization of spectral lines from atoms and small molecules by expressing position and momentum in terms of the emission/absorption energies involved: the idea was that if an atom emitted light with a frequency $\omega$, the position and momentum must oscillate at that frequency in a way when transitioning between orbitals. Since these position and momentum components/amplitudes are associated with pairs of indices (i.e. the orbitals involved in the transition), they are naturally interpreted as (time-dependent) matrices.  The main conceptual leap was to suspect that it multiplication over these matrix indices could be meaningful, and that the associated matrix commutator(s) correspond to the Poisson bracket operation from classical mechanics.  This may have been motivated by the observation that, as a "matrix", the Hamiltonian "function" would have been constant on each orbital/level, zero on off-diagonal elements, and commutation of the Hamiltonian with $x$ and $p$ as matrices would reproduce $\dot x$ and $\dot p$.  Since this was meant as a precise model of electronic orbitals, I think Heisenberg's model was not meant entirely heuristically.
For more information on this, see Weinberg, Lectures on Quantum Mechanics.
